# calculate the service tax in django admin model save method

Tags: python, django

want to calculate the service tax in django admin save method but getting one error

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
   extra_charge = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)
   driver_allownce_charge = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)
   night_hault_charge = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)
   toll_and_parking = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)
   starting_kilometer=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
   ending_kilometer=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
   service_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)
   grand_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.total_kilometer:
            self.total_kilometer = self.ending_kilometer - self.starting_kilometer
        if not self.grand_total:
            minivl  = self.extra_charge + self.driver_allownce_charge + self.night_hault_charge
            tax = minivl*4.444
            final_tax = tax/100
            print final_tax
            self.grand_total = self.extra_charge + self.driver_allownce_charge + self.night_hault_charge + self.toll_and_parking
        return super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but getting one error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Decimal' and 'float
```

total_kilometer getting saved properly

Comment: need to first check that all items used in the math equation are set to NON NULL values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is, since you have various fields nullable, that is causing the issue. You need to check if the value exists, else handle it gracefully.

For example:

```
minivl  = self.extra_charge or 0 + self.driver_allownce_charge or 0 + self.night_hault_charge or 0
```

This way, if the `self.extra_charge` evaluates to `None`, use the value `0`. Note that you could also be handling this in the Form, or providing a default value of 0.

EDIT:

For the issue with unsupported decimal, and float types, the error message is quite obvious.

Just cast the decimal type to `float`

Example:

```
float(self.night_hault_charge or 0)
```

Comment: please check edited question. getting diffrent error unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Decimal' and 'float

Comment: Please dont change the question - create a heading called EDIT (or something) and edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you didn't declare fields for `starting_kilometer` and `ending_kilometer` or assign values to them. So the error complains about operations on `NoneType` value:

```
    if not self.total_kilometer:
        self.total_kilometer = self.ending_kilometer - self.starting_kilometer
```

Comment: sorry its there i forgot to put in question. edited the question.

Comment: @Gaurav You didn't assign any value to these two fields before invoke save(), did you? That's mainly the error message complaining `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' `

Comment: yah you are right but now i am getting unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Decimal' and 'float' this error

Comment: @Gaurav try declare them both as `DecimalField` or `IntegerField`, or use `float()` to convert Integer value to Decimal value